# How to obtain singular integral of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Consider the following nonlinear ODE

$$(xy^{\prime}-y)^{2}=x^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})$$

find singular integral of this ODE.

I got its general solution by substituting $y=vx$ which is $\log(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)+c$.
How to get singular integral ?
Whether singular integral mean singular solution ?
How to apply c-discriminate?
Am I on right track ?
Please help to solve this example.

Comment: singular integral DOESN't necessarily mean singular solution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying $p$ dicriminent $$4x^2y^2-4(x^2y^2+x^4y^2+4x^6)=0$$ $$y=x$$ which the singular solution

Comment: But why don't we take y=-x as the singular integral?