# To find a singular integral to $(xy^{\prime}-y)^{2}=x^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a self study in differential equations and came across the following problem in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525631/how-to-obtain-singular-integral-of-ordinary-differential-equations) post

$$(xy^{\prime}-y)^{2}=x^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})$$

to find singular integral of this ODE.

The solution given there isn't helpful at all. Is there a standard method to solve these type of equations. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Considering the equation $$(xy^{\prime}-y)^{2}-x^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})=0$$ start using $y=u\,x$. This leads to $$u'^2+u^2-1=0\implies u'=\pm \sqrt{1+u^2}$$ which is separable and easy to integrate..